How to add a value to a new, blank custom field in customSchema
I'm trying to add a value to a custom field within a customSchema using Google Apps Script. Whether I add the customSchema using the Google Admin Console, or through Apps Script, I run into the same problem: The customSchema can't be found with the Admin SDK with Apps Script until I put a value in manually using GAC.
function updateCustomSchemaData(userEmail, schemaName, fieldName, newValue) {
  // userEmail = 'user@email.com'
  // schemaName = 'User_Information'
  // fieldName = 'Site_Code'
  // newValue = 'test'
  try {
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);
    var schemaData = user.customSchemas[schemaName];
    schemaData[fieldName] = newValue;
    AdminDirectory.Users.update(user, userEmail);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error updating custom schema data: " + error);
  }
}

I confirm through GAC that the field exists before running updateCustomSchemaData.

When running the code, I get the following.
Error updating custom schema data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User_Information')
If I check the output of user, it doesn't contain any customSchema.
If I edit the field in GAC and add a value to that customSchema manually, var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail); will have the customSchema in it.
  "customSchemas": {
    "User_Information": {
      "Site_Code": "This is a test"
    }
  },


I can confirm that the schema does exist, since I have a separate, working function to create the schema if it doesn't (using AdminDirectory.schemas.insert), and as long as the schema is in GAC, even if it's not in user, I get this:
Failed addSchema with error API call to directory.schemas.insert failed with error: Entity Already Exists: resource.schemaName
TL;DR At first glance, a newly created custom field in a customSchema can't be seen by AdminDirectory.Users.get, and AdminDirectory.Users.update can't a value to the field. I'm hoping this is incorrect, and I just don't know how.
Please help me find a way to update a value in a newly created, blank  custom field in a customSchema.
UPDATE #1:
Current code, doesn't error, but doesn't add the value to Site Code.
function updateUser() {
  // update individual user, given email, to make Site Code match buildingId
  const user1Email = "user1@email.org";
  //const user2Email = 'user2@email.org';
  try {
    var user = getUser(user1Email);
    var userId = user.customerId
    const myFunction = () => {
        AdminDirectory.Users.update({
          "customSchemas": {
            "User_Information": {
              "Site_Code": "This is a test"
            }
          }
        }, user1Email);
      myFunction();
    }
    var user = getUser(user1Email);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}


Can you confirm what I'm trying to add a value to a customSchema using Google Apps Script means? Apologies if I didn't quite catch what the question was, but from what I understand, you'd like to add another Custom fields like the Site Code in this sample image. Would that be correct?

Not quite. I want to add a value into a custom field in a customSchema, which is my own misclarification.
In Google Admin Console, taking your image as the starting point, I hit Save on that box to make the Employee Information schema with the Site Code field.
In GAC, now I can go to TestUser and see Site Code is empty and says Add Site Code. At this point, Google Apps Script can't add "Test" as the value for TestUser's Site Code.
I have to find the user in GAC, and enter a Site Code manually. Once I do that, GAS can make changes to the Site Code's value.

@Saddles sorry realized I probably needed to tag you in that reply but missed the edit window.

Understood. To confirm, you'd like to use Google Apps Script to add a value in the Site Code of the User_Information's customSchemas. Would that be correct? If so, your expected output is something like this sample image.

@Saddles Correct.

Method: users.get isn't actually needed when using Method: users.update in adding a value in the Site Code of the User_Information's customSchemas. I'll post what I used as an answer so that you may check if it's what you wanted.

The goal is to add a value to a custom field within a customSchema using Google Apps Script created by Method: schemas.insert. The Error updating custom schema data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User_Information') is because Method: users.get doesn't return customSchemas if there's no value to it even if projection is set to full.
To resolve this, use Method: users.update directly like this:
const myFunction = () => {
  AdminDirectory.Users.update({
    "customSchemas": {
      "User_Information": {
        "Site_Code": "This is a test"
      }
    }
  }, "user@email.com");
}


Note: I noticed that Method: users.get only returns a value for customSchemas if projection is set to full and there's a value to it.

OUTPUT
BEFORE

AFTER


Running this function, I don't get any errors, but it also doesn't seem to place a value in Site Code for me. Prior to you testing that code, did you at any point put a value in Site Code?

No. Although you'll need to refresh the page before you see what was added. I tried it with another user, and it worked without any issues.

I've added an update to the original post with my current code, using this function you've got working. It doesn't seem to error out, which is good, but I can't get it to add the value, either.

Does the same thing happen when you try to Browse in Incognito mode?

It doesn't show in incognito mode or with AdminDirectory.users.get with projection set to full either.
I would love to know why this issue is happening, and I'm happy to keep working on it because I still have no clue why it's not working, but I've found an alternative solution to the root problem.
While we've been troubleshooting this, my coworker managing GCDS/Google Cloud Domain Sync mentioned that it can make and populate this field using a direct LDAP mapping, which I didn't know GCDS could do.

It's good to hear that there's an alternative for you on this! If you're still willing to troubleshoot, can you recreate the entire custom attribute? I tried everything with a different Google Workspace account, and it worked out properly. Kindly add some logging statements as well in the script so that you'll see what the response is to the code.

I'm definitely open to keep going, is there any specific logging that you'd like to see? I've recreated the entire custom attribute multiple times, both using the same and different names, and each time stumble into the same problem, so if there's specific kinds of logs that would be helpful I'd like to make sure I use that.

Could you add console.log(AdminDirectory.Users.get("user@email.com", { "projection": "full" })); after AdminDirectory.Users.update()? What I got when I tested this is something like customSchemas: { User_Information: { Site_Code: 'This is a test' } }.

Also, instead of running the function through Ctrl + R or the usual Run button, can you try the Debug button instead?

Found the problem, at least in this case. I've got myFunction(); should've been below, not above, the }.
Aside from that, I believe my problem was - and I could've sworn I'd tried this, but must be mistaken, or made other errors at the same time - I didn't use {customSchemas: { User_Information: { Site_Code: 'This is a test' } } as the first parameter of AdminDirectory.Users.update.
I'm not sure how this has eluded me the whole time, but thank you for your help, and your patience as I stumbled my way through this with you.
